# I am struggling to print a specific Id matched to the member i have entered it with. When i say it just prints any.?

Tags: java

this is what i have completed so far, can you please advise me in the right direction. thank you.

```
public class Member {

  private String FirstName;
  private String LastName;
  private int memberId;
  private int Id;
  private String phoneNumber;
  private String member;

  public Member(String FirstName, String LastName, int uniqueId, String phoneNumber) {

    this.Id = uniqueId;
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
    this.LastName = LastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;    
  }

  public void addMember(String FirstName, String LastName, int uniqueId, String phoneNumber) {

  }

  public String getMember() {
    return FirstName + LastName;
  }

  public String getlistOfMembers() {
    return (FirstName + LastName);
  }

  public int getId() {
    return Id;
  }

  public void printMemberId(int Id) {
    if (Id <= 100) {
      System.out.println("Member Id: " + this.Id);
      System.out.println("first name:  " + FirstName);
      System.out.println("LastName:  " + LastName);
      System.out.println("Member phone number:  " + phoneNumber);
    } else
      System.out.println("incorrect");
    ;
  }

  public void getMemberDetails() {
    if (Id <= 100) {
      System.out.println("Member Id: " + Id);
      System.out.println("first name:  " + FirstName);
      System.out.println("LastName:  " + LastName);
      System.out.println("Member phone number:  " + phoneNumber);
    } else
      System.out.println("incorrect");
    ;
  }
}
```

this is what i have completed so far, can you please advise me in the right direction. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you put things that should be in two classes into one. You seem to want a `Member` class to store information about one member. And another class to contain multiple members with ids. Maybe this separation helps:

```
public class Member {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int memberId;
    private int id;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String member;

    public Member(String firstName, String lastName, int uniqueId, String phoneNumber) {

        this.id = uniqueId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void printMemberDetails() {
        System.out.println("Member id: " + id);
        System.out.println("first name:  " + firstName);
        System.out.println("lastName:  " + lastName);
        System.out.println("Member phone number:  " + phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

And then for the collection:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Members {

    // List of members    
    private List<Member> memberList;
    // for performance you may want to use a map to find elements faster
    // private Map<Integer, Member> memberMap;

    public Members() {
        memberList = new ArrayList<>();
        //memberMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addMember(String firstName, String lastName, int uniqueId, String phoneNumber) {
        // maybe check if the id already exists
        memberList.add(new Member(firstName, lastName, uniqueId, phoneNumber));
    }

    public Collection<Member> getlistOfMembers() {
        return memberList;
    }

    public void printMemberId(int id) {
        for (Member m : memberList) {
            if (m.getId() == id) {
                m.printMemberDetails();
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Members members = new Members();
        members.addMember("Hans", "Mueller", 8, "98365402");
        members.addMember("Hans", "Meister", 233, "98365402");

        members.printMemberId(8); // prints Hans Mueller
        members.printMemberId(123); // prints nothing
        members.printMemberId(233); // prints Hans Meister
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do. According to the `addMember()` method, you probably want to use some kind of Collection, don't you? In that case you can either implement your own Collection, or make a class with collection as an attribute.

Comment: Yes i want to add a collection of members but i am struggling with adding the integer and string together. Also i am struggling with printing the right member off with the given Id?

Comment: Well, you have the `memberID` and `uniqueID` in one class. If you want to print member with certain `uniqueID`, you can just find him in your collection by that ID.

Comment: I am not sure how i store more than one member with Id?

Comment: @Cajova_Houba This should be a comment instead of an answer